# Is ios blocking local notifications considered as harmful?

Tags: ios, cordova, notifications, phonegap-plugins, local

I have an app made with phonegap which is using a third-party plugin for displaying local notifications. (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)
I deployed it on my device, and in the beginning it worked well. However after the app sent dozens of notifications (very frequently and with same text) at some point my iphone started not showing the notifications. I tried to delete the app, and deploy again, then the confirmation dialog popped up again for allowing notifications from the app, but they still didn't show up.
When i deployed it on an other device, it worked well again, also in the emulator. 
Is it possible that ios somehow blocked notifications from this app, because it considered them as harmful/spam?

Comment: It's local notification, not push. So not using any APNs, i don't know if it makes any difference. But if that's the case, is there any way to unblock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum number of scheduled notification is 64. If you are reached the maximum you can't add more local notifications without removing the old ones or after firing the scheduled notifications.

In the apple [documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html), it mentions as follows

> Each app on a device is limited to 64 scheduled local notifications.
>   The system discards scheduled notifications in excess of this limit,
>   keeping only the 64 notifications that will fire the soonest.
>   Recurring notifications are treated as a single notification.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of [64 scheduled notifications per app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html), so, if you schedule more - only first 64 will arive.

> Each app on a device is limited to 64 scheduled local notifications. The system discards scheduled notifications in excess of this limit, keeping only the 64 notifications that will fire the soonest. Recurring notifications are treated as a single notification.

However, there is a way to be sure that all 64 are scheduled - just pass them in packs by 64 notifications each.
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7721445/4108415) for more info.