# Not receiving local scheduled notifications on iOS

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

My CRNA (Expo) app schedules local notifications for event reminders. The notifications are scheduled and received perfectly on Android, but not iOS.

I've created a reduced test case: https://github.com/nandastone/crna-expo-local-notification-test

Tapping the "Send Immediate Notification" button calls `Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync()` which IS then received by the callback.

Tapping the "Send Delayed Notification" button schedules a notification in 5 seconds with `Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync()` which IS NOT received by the callback.

I'm aware that notifications are not displayed by iOS if the app is in the foreground (https://forums.expo.io/t/psa-reminder-notifications-in-ios-foregrounded-apps/641), but I'm not receiving notifications at all in the `Notifications.addListener()` callback. Closing the app after scheduling a notification also has no effect.

I'm fairly certain the `Permissions.REMOTE_NOTIFICATIONS` check is not required for local notifications (it certainly isn't on Android), but I've included it to be sure.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my reduced test case I was missing an event listener for receiving notifications (`Notification.addListener()`).

The issue in my real app, however, was the [limit of 64 local notifications on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721362/schedule-number-of-local-notifications). The app was scheduling more than 64 notifications at once, and they were not all firing.